# How to create a textbox to accept emoticon in QML?

Tags: javascript, qml

i am trying to create a textbox which will accept a emoticon image as part of its text.

Any sugestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tell your textbox that you want it to display rich text. When you write text, replace your emoticons with HTML `<img>` tags pointing to the emoticon picture.

**Edit :** example with a smiley example (`:-)`)

In your text box, you want to replace the `:-)` smiley with this picture : [image: smile smiley - google "smiley smile gif" on Google image to find another ones if you want]. Assume that the picture is in a file called "smile.jpg". When you write text, replace `:-)` by `<img src="my/path/to/smile.jpg" alt=":-)"/>`. When you write a backspace to erase the smiley, you can replace the whole HTML `<img>` tag by `:-` (`:-)` without the final `)`)

Comment: How do i handle a backspace in such a case,coz then it shows html tag

Comment: I don't understand what you want to say. Can you explain it ?

Comment: Trying to create a textbox like the one used in whatsapp